# Multiple nameservers, how do they work when they can't resolve a query?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, authoritative

I have 4 nameserver set for my domain: ns1.nameserver.com, ns2.nameserver.com, ect...

I know that if one is down an other one will be used. But if the first is up and running and is asked for a domain it doesn't know, will the request be passed to a second nameserver?

To clarify:
I registered a domain.com. Then I specified 2 nameservers (the authoritative I think its their name) that my hosting gave me. I've also an other hosting, I'd like to use it for some subdomains, if I add its nameservers as authoritative what happens?

Comment: please clarify 'set for my domain'.  In normal DNS speak that means the ones listed as authoritative for your DNS domain name, but that doesn't appear to be what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the request will be passed 'upstream' to more authoritative nameservers.

[Domain Name System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)

It sounds like what you are really asking is what happens when one of your name servers has not cached a particular query.  In this case it will follow the normal DNS rules and go upstream for the answer and cache it for the TTL period.

If, on the other hand, you are asking what happens if your names servers are missing a record for a domain they are supposed to be authoritative for, then that particular server will respond with a 'record not found'.

Comment: the cas is "record not found", the client will ask an other nameserver or not?

Comment: If it is a domain that the servers is supposed to be authoritative for, then no.  At that point the client has received an official response of 'not found'.

Answer (score 0):

If the article Peter linked for you isn't sufficient you can Google for "DNS tutorial".

Edit:

```
the cas is "record not found", the client will ask an other nameserver or not?
```

Not. "Record not found" is an answer. The client will only try another nameserver if the one it tried didn't answer at all.